# Canon printer only prints images, no characters!

Tags: macos, printer

I have a MacBook Pro and a Canon LBP3010B printer. For some reason my printer doesn't print any characters, only images.

I'm not sure what the problem is, any ideas why the printer would behave in this way?

Comment: How are you trying to print characters?

Comment: In a simple way. I tried to print a pdf file and a text file.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the printer resolution is set too low. I have had this problem in the past when I was trying to save ink.

Comment: Thanx, I will try to set the resolution and let you know.

Comment: I needed to set mine (old: HP 6L) to print at its max, 600 and I had to make sure that the econo mode was set to off. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem.

The way I "solved" is it to convert all text in any PDF to images first. With ghostscript installed through brew, I did, with file.pdf as the file, in bash

```
gs -dNoOutputFonts -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o file2.pdf file.pdf
```

that produces another PDF with the text as curves. That prints well.

edit: Oh, installing a new driver from canon website also fixed it.